# Exporting DataGridView data to Excel file in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, excel, datagridview, export

I need to export data from DataGridView (in my WinForms application) to excel file. I googled some tutorials on the subject, but I'm having hard time getting any of the available solutions to work.

I started with [this tutorial](http://www.gridview.net/export-datagridview-to-excel-in-c/). But when I try to export datagridview to excel file i get Unhandled COMException in:

```
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass ExcelApp = new 
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass();
```

I've also tried [this tutorial](http://csharp.net-informations.com/excel/csharp-excel-datagridview.htm), but with the same result.

Another of the articles I've found and read was [this one](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/hrojasara/export-datagridview-to-excel-in-C-Sharp/). Couldn't get code to work, probably because I can't find `Microsoft Excel 12.0 object library` in the `COM tab` of `Add Reference` dialog.

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate.

Comment: Does the Unhandled COMException occur when you try to instantiate the ApplicationClass, or at some later point? If it's at a later point, can you add all of the code you have?

Comment: I believe it occurs when I try to instantiate the ApplicationClass. The code I'm using is available [here](http://www.gridview.net/export-datagridview-to-excel-in-c/).

Comment: Does it have to be an excel file, would .csv be ok?

Comment: It has to be an excel file, .csv wouldn't be satisfying.

Comment: What excel functionality are you using then?

Comment: @RalphWillgoss I'm not using excel functionality.

Comment: If your not using any excel functionality, why the use of the component, why not convert the DataGrid to a csv?

Comment: @RalphWillgoss I wanted to learn exporting to Excel file in case I would need this knowledge in the future, when using excel functionality would be mandatory. And I did learn to do this, thanks to other users. What  you suggested was avoiding the problem, not solving it.

Comment: So long as we get you to the answer you require, that's what matters. Part of this is suggesting alternatives, we don't know your constraints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If those libraries are not installed, you can download them from Microsoft:

For Specific office versions, see here:

[Office 2003 Update: Redistributable Primary Interop Assemblies](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=20923)

[2007 Microsoft Office System Update: Redistributable Primary Interop Assemblies](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=18346)

[Microsoft Office 2010: Primary Interop Assemblies Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=3508)

Once you install the correct one, you should be able to find the library in the 'Add reference' section of the tutorials

Comment: I've looked at links in your answer. But I can't use any of these files if I don't have Microsoft Office installed. Maybe this is a stupid question, but I wasn't aware of this. Is it absolutely necessary? And I was able to _Add a reference to the `Microsoft.Office.Interop` to my project from .NET components_, following [this tutorial](http://www.gridview.net/export-datagridview-to-excel-in-c/), so I still don't know what's the problem with this solution.

Comment: @beam022 - Thats correct, you need Excel to be installed in order for this to work.

Answer (score 1):

One day I did what you need but I got it in VB.Net

So you just need to create a Class Library project and in that class
use my method so you can reference it through C#.

Take a look at this link (translate it to English):
http://foro.elhacker.net/net/aporte_exportar_datagridview_a_excel_pdf_y_html-t299075.0.html

and also you can download my example from here and re-use my method:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/15208254/stackoverflow/ExportarData.rar

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Excel Package Plus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/) and export your data without a need for excel, or any other external dependancy